# Salt crystal growing inside a mold inside a jar

Tags: home-experiment

I have recently found an experiment where you can grow a salt crystal on a jar. The experiment works like this: we take a jar, fill it with hot/warm water and start dissolving salt in it until it saturates (add food coloring - optional) and then leave it for a couple days after which on the bottom of the jar there will be a salt platform with crystals growing out of it. We take this formation out of the water and break it into pieces and take the nicest crystal, tie it with a string and then suspend it back in the water and over time (1-2 months) our crystal will grow in size.

My question is, if I create a solid plastic mold in which the water from the jar can infiltrate, if I put this mold in the saturated water and the crystal suspended right at the very top part of the mold and make sure the water is saturated from time to time, will the crystal grow perfectly or almost perfect all the way to the feet of the mold? I mean I want to start making salt figurines using a 3d printed mold and the salt experiment is it going to work?Thank you for you help I really appreciate your work.

Comment: I was wondering too
https://www.amazon.com/Thames-Kosmos-643522-Crystal-Growing/dp/B007WDGZUM
you could make something similar?
:)
Pam

Comment: If you are still interested in this I'd be glad to give my thoughts on the best way to go about it.  But as hard as you tried to describe it I'm not sure I'm getting it. A picture is worth way more than a thousand works in my opinion ;)  If you could post a sketch of what you are proposing that would be tremendously helpful!